# Query data in realtime database with AngularFire in nested structures

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have the following path in the Firebase Realtime database:

```
/dataTables/userId/dayDate/tableID/rowWithData
```

The structure of `rowWithData` is like this:

```
{
    "-NLBD8PD7i5DPfdgF": {
      "name": "Demo 1",
      "rows": {
        "-NLBD8RiJeyZpnKg8iKI": {
          "lastEdit": 1676495720665,
          "name": "Data 1",
          "priority": 1
        },
        "-NLBPODZMfFFXKTFDo7p": {
          "lastEdit": 1676495720665,
          "name": "Data 2",
          "priority": 5
        }
      }
  },
  "-NLBD8PD7asdas": {
    "name": "Demo 2",
    "rows": {
      "-NLBD8RiJeyZpnKg8iKI": {
        "lastEdit": 1676495720665,
        "name": "Data 3 here",
        "priority": 1
      },
      "-NLBPODZMfFFXKTFDo7p": {
        "lastEdit": 1676495720665,
        "name": "Data 4 here",
        "priority": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying these queries - the first one returns 0:

```
this.angularFireDatabase
  .list(`dataTables/${this.userInfo.uid}`, ref => ref.limitToFirst(50).equalTo(`search term`))
  .snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("search data", data);
  })
```

The second one returns all the data from the database under this path `/data/userId/dayDate`:

```
this.angularFireDatabase
  .list(`dataTables/${this.userInfo.uid}`, ref => ref.orderByChild('rows'))
  .snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("search data", data);
    debugger;
  })
```

When I add the `.equalsTo()` function with any term it returns no results.

I am trying to search in the path `/data/userId` for all values that are in the search term.

Here are some info but I didn't find anything practical with my situation.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/compat/rtdb/querying-lists.md

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: How does the `dataTables/${this.userInfo.uid}` in your code correlate to the JSON data you shared?

Comment: Sorry, the path is /dataTables/userId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering data in Firebase Realtime Database is a two-step process:

1. First you order the data on a value by calling `orderByKey`, `orderByValue`, or `orderByChild`. This value has to be at a fixed path under each child node that is directly under the path that you query.
2. Then then you can filter on the value you ordered on, for example with the `equalTo` operation.

Since you don't call any `orderBy`, your node are ordered by their priority or key and none of those priorities/keys match the value you filter on.

---

If you have a `ref` that points to root of the JSON you shared, you can filter on the `name` property with:

```
ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("Demo 1")
```

This would give you a list with one resulting node; the `-NLBD8PD7i5DPfdgF`.

---

If the `ref` variable points to the `-NLBD8PD7i5DPfdgF` in the JSON you shared, you can filter the rows of that specific node on their `name` property with:

```
ref.child("rows").orderByChild("name").equalTo("Data 2")
```

This would give you a list with a single resulting node again, the row with key `-NLBPODZMfFFXKTFDo7p`.

---

There is no way to search across multiple properties for any of them to contain the value. If you need that, consider using a dedicated search engine rather than Firebase Realtime Database.

---

There is no way to filter across the entire JSON for values in a specific row, as that no longer meets the requirement that the value to filter on exists on a fixed path under each *direct* child node.

For more on that and possible solutions by changing the data model, see [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested) and [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: These return an empty Array  `ref.child("rows"))` - `ref.child("rows").orderByChild("name")` - `ref.child("rows").orderByChild("name").equalTo("demo")`

Comment: I think the problem is how to get pass `/date/`

Comment: Can `ref.child("rows")` go down and jump beyond the `/date/`?

Comment: Seems not to be possible to get pass /date/ without specifying it in the path. It would be a great feature to be able to jump beyond a path https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#child

Comment: I tried to be clear in my answer on the requirements for this code to work. The first example works if you have a `ref` that points to root of the JSON you shared. The second example works if `ref` that points to the `-NLBD8PD7i5DPfdgF` in the JSON you shared